# Error in migrating and upgrading in Flask with sqlalchemy_utils ChoiceType

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I am using flask-migrate to adjust my database changes.

```
$python manage.py db init
$python manage.py db migrate
```

These work fine but when i use

```
$python manage.py db upgrade
```

This error happens

```
TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Command object at 0x7fa134712890>: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'length'
```

This is my **models.py**

```
class JobsModel(db.Model):
JOB_STATUS_TYPES = [
  (u"data_upload_in_progress", u"Data Upload in Progress"),
  (u"data_upload_success", u"Data Upload Success"),
  (u"data_validation_success", u"Data Validation Success"),
  (u"data_validation_error", u"Data Validation Error")
   ]

 __tablename__ = 'jobs'

 job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
 usecase_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('use_cases.id'), nullable = False)
 usecase = db.relationship('UseCaseModel')
 user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
 version_id = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
 job_status = db.Column(ChoiceType(JOB_STATUS_TYPES))
 dataset_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('datasets.dataset_id'), nullable=False)
 dataset = db.relationship('DataSetModel')
 training_details = db.Column(JSON)
 testing_details = db.Column(JSON)
```

This is my file after I do the migrate command **2easaw23523sa.py**

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from mi import mig
def upgrade():
   op.create_table('jobs',
   sa.Column('job_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
   sa.Column('usecase_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
   sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
   sa.Column('version_id', sa.Float(), nullable=True),
   sa.Column('job_status', mig.ChoiceType(length=255), nullable=True),
   sa.Column('dataset_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
   sa.Column('training_details', sa.JSON(), nullable=True),
   sa.Column('testing_details', sa.JSON(), nullable=True),
   sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['dataset_id'], ['datasets.dataset_id'], ),
   sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['usecase_id'], ['use_cases.id'], ),
   sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['users.id'], ),
   sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('job_id')
   )

def downgrade():
   # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
   op.drop_table('jobs')

# ### end Alembic commands ###
```

**Note** - statement ***from mi import mig*** appears because if used the process given in this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by replacing `length=255` with `{1:2}` (or any other python object that is Truthy, and can be passed into `dict()` without throwing an exception).

i.e. replace the line

`sa.Column('job_status', mig.ChoiceType(length=255), nullable=True),`

With

`sa.Column('job_status', mig.ChoiceType({1:2}), nullable=True),`